# ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I am consistently getting this error when connecting to an Oracle DB server - I don't know which version - using the odp.net connector (v.4.121.2.0). Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x00000C27): ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel
   at OracleInternal.Network.ReaderStream.Read(OraBuf OB)
   at OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.GetDataFromNetwork()
   at OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.Read(Boolean bIgnoreData)
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCDataTypeNegotiation.ReadResponse()
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.DoDataTypeNegotiation()
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Do you get anything in the database alert log at the same time? Or maybe the SQL\*Net log if it's happening after the connection has been open for a certain amount of time. If you're getting it consistently, what are the consistent circumstances?

Comment: Start by checking the Alert log in the database server to look for errors during the time you are trying to connect... then research and solve those errors. Also, check to see if a firewall could be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

ODP.NET, Managed Driver supports connecting to Oracle DB server 10.2 or higher. It does not support DB 10.

Check if this is your case.